# NoSuchElementException with two ArrayLists

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class CSVReader
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Lunch.csv"));
    ArrayList<String> AccountNum = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> AccountBal = new ArrayList<String>();
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
       AccountNum.add(scanner.next());
       AccountBal.add(scanner.next());
    }
    scanner.close();
    display(AccountNum, AccountBal);
 }

 public static void display(ArrayList AccountNum, ArrayList AccountBal)
 {
     System.out.println("\nThe size of the list is " + AccountNum.size());
     for(int x = 0; x < AccountNum.size(); ++x)
     {
        System.out.println("position " + x + " Number: " + AccountNum.get(x));
        System.out.println("position " + x + " Number: " + AccountBal.get(x));
     }
 }


}
```

This program is supposed to read from a CSV file into two arrays. It compiles fine but when I run it it throws the NoSuchElementException. The program works when only one array is used. Does anyone know why it throws this exception and how to solve it?

Comment: You are using `scanner.next` 2 times after `scanner.hasNext()`

Comment: Which line throws the exception, do you know?  Also, your while loop seems to assume that there will be an even number of elements to add.  Is this the case?  Maybe there is an odd number of elements from the csv and the very last `AccountBal.add(scanner.next());` is where the issue lies...

Answer (score 4):

Edit: To correct my answer for ChrisCM's comment, this will prevent the exception you're receiving while still alternating scanner inputs.

```
while(scanner.hasNext())
{
   AccountNum.add(scanner.next());
   if(scanner.hasNext())
       AccountBal.add(scanner.next());
}
```

You may find that you end up with uneven lists (the last element of AccountNum will be whitespace), you can fix this with

```
if(AccountNum.get(AccountNum.size() - 1).trim().equals("")) {
    AccountNum.remove(AccountNum.size() - 1);
}
```

If you still have uneven lists then you'll need to debug the program to figure out the problem.

Another way to parse the input:

```
while(scanner.hasNext())
{
   String temp = scanner.next();
   if(temp.trim().equals("") && scanner.hasNext()) {
       throw new Exception("This shouldn't happen");
   } else { 
       AccountNum.add(temp);
   }
   if(scanner.hasNext())
       AccountBal.add(scanner.next());
}
```

You can also switch to using a library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), which can deal with whitespace tomfoolery in the input file.

Comment: While this will not throw an exception I doubt it functions the way he wants it to.  Clearly AccountNum and AccountBal do not represent the same information.

Comment: I like this much better, however, I'm still not confident it will work for him.  We need to see how he has formatted his input file!

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer if he was parsing the account balance to a double or BigDecimal - there would be more opportunity for things to break if the input was formatted/parsed incorrectly

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the if statement in the while loop and that got rid of my error and then I used ChrisCM's soulution.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably an odd number of items in your input file.  Your code is assuming that every single account number has one, and only one balance.  If your file does indeed meet this requirement, it could be your use of:

```
scanner.useDelimeter(",");
```

Which you probably want to be

```
scanner.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
```

Comment: Then accept this as the answer please.  Note: that some of the error checking and exception handling from Zim-zam is still good practice!  I just happened to have made this stupid mistake before, and kinda knew it was what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

One of the account numbers does not have a balance or it is blank, or there is an extra comma somwhere...